# do I have any alternative to cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

`enter code here`I am Developing a complex report, for which i need to select some data from table-1 and then perform some processing on data from tabel-2, tabel-3,table-4 on behalf of data from table-1.

like

```
select a,b,c, from table-1

while not rs(table-1).eof

processing data from table-2,
processing data from table-3,
processing data from table-4
```

do

I have tried but sub query can not solve my problem.
as I know cursor is my only option, if there is any other solution please guide me

regards.

at the time i am doing it by processing data on client side and then saving it into a temp table in data base and then fetching records from that table into crystal report. here is my code

```
rs.Open "SELECT distinct Empid,empSalary as EmpSalary,EmpJobStatus From TEmployee where EmpJobStatus ='HIRED' and EmpID not in ( SELECT distinct Empid From VEmpPromotion where convert(VARCHAR(10), PromSalaryMonth , 101)='" & Format(FirstDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "') Union SELECT distinct Empid,promempSalary as EmpSalary,PromEmpJobStatus as EmpJobStatus From VEmpPromotion where PromEmpJobStatus ='HIRED' and convert(VARCHAR(10), PromSalaryMonth , 101)='" & Format(FirstDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "'", cn, 3, 2


While Not rs.EOF
rsD1.Open "select sum(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,timein,timeout))/60 as HoursWorked ,count(EmpLEave) as EmpLeave,count(TimeIN) as DaysWorked from Tattendance where EmpId =" & rs![EmpId] & " and convert(VARCHAR(10), Attendate, 101)>='" & Format(FirstDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "' and convert(VARCHAR(10), attendate, 101)<='" & Format(LastDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "'", cn, 3, 2
rsD2.Open "select sum(amount),SUM(CASE EmpTrancID WHEN 1  then amount  ELSE 0 END) AS 'SalaryPaid',SUM(CASE EmpTrancID WHEN 2  then amount  ELSE 0 END) AS 'SalaryAdvancePaid',SUM(CASE EmpTrancID WHEN 3  then amount  ELSE 0 END) AS 'WeeklyIncentivePaid',SUM(CASE EmpTrancID WHEN 4  then amount  ELSE 0 END) AS 'MonthlyIncentivePaid',SUM(CASE EmpTrancID WHEN 5  then amount  ELSE 0 END) AS 'InitialAdvancePaid',SUM(CASE EmpTrancID WHEN 6  then amount  ELSE 0 END) AS 'OtherPayments',SUM(CASE EmpTrancID WHEN 7  then amount  ELSE 0 END) AS 'SalaryAdvanceBack',SUM(CASE EmpTrancID WHEN 8  then amount  ELSE 0 END) AS 'InitialAdvanceBack'From TSalAdvance where TrancStatus =1 and EmpId =" & rs![EmpId] & " and convert(VARCHAR(10), PaidDate, 101)<= '" & Format(DTSearch, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "' and convert(VARCHAR(10), PaidDate, 101)>= '" & Format(FirstDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "'", cn, 3, 2
rsD4.Open "select sum(amount),SUM(CASE EmpTrancID WHEN 8  then amount  ELSE 0 END) AS 'TInitialAdvanceBack',SUM(CASE EmpTrancID WHEN 5  then amount  ELSE 0 END) AS 'TInitialAdvancePaid'From TSalAdvance where TrancStatus =1 and EmpId =" & rs![EmpId] & " and convert(VARCHAR(10), SalaryMonth, 101)<'" & Format(LastDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "'", cn, 3, 2
rsD5.Open "select sum(amount),SUM(CASE EmpTrancID WHEN 2  then amount  ELSE 0 END) AS 'SalaryAdvancePaid',SUM(CASE EmpTrancID WHEN 7  then amount  ELSE 0 END) AS 'SalaryAdvanceBack'From TSalAdvance where TrancStatus =1 and EmpId =" & rs![EmpId] & " and convert(VARCHAR(10), SalaryMonth, 101)>'" & Format(LastDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "'", cn, 3, 2
If IsNull(rsD5![SalaryAdvancePaid]) Then NextAdvPaid = 0 Else NextAdvPaid = rsD5![SalaryAdvancePaid]
If IsNull(rsD5![SalaryAdvanceBack]) Then NextAdvBAck = 0 Else NextAdvBAck = rsD5![SalaryAdvanceBack]
rsD3.Open "select * from SalarySummaryAll", cn, 3, 2
rsD3.AddNew
rsD3![EmpId] = rs![EmpId]
rsD3![EmpSalary] = rs![EmpSalary]
rsD3![EmpJobStatus] = Trim(rs![EmpJobStatus])
.........
.........
rsD3.Update
rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

Comment: Please, show the table structure, sample input and desired outupt. Without that information your quesiton is too vague to be answered.

Comment: It is payroll report which include following info

Comment: @user1115284 - There's rarely a need to use cursors unless your requirement is to slow down the operation but as jachguate already mentioned, it is imposible to give you more precise advice on how to solve this with a set based approach.

Comment: sorry for your inconvenience.It is payroll report which include following info. It takes employee id from Promotion-table and emp-table and then collect its information from attendance-table including time-in, time-out, leaves, absents, short and extra hours, some processing is done on this info, then it takes info from salary table, then from salary-advance-table calculate salary on behalf of attendance-tabl. all table are connected with emp-id , need processing data between two date intervals.

Comment: If you need i can give all 5-6 tables structure with data types, but i was thinking i will make question much longer and complex

Comment: @user1115284 don't post that in comments, rather edit your question!

Comment: @user1115284 I know you edited your question, but... did you read my first comment?

Comment: which comment you are talking about, one for editing question or ???

Answer (score 0):

Your queries seem quite long, but you don't seem to use much variables there.

I don't see  why you couldn't use some inner and left (outer) joins here like :

```
insert into SalarySummaryAll(EmpId, EmpSalary, ...)
select (TEmployeeAlias.EmpIdAlias, TEmployeeAlias.EmpSalaryAlias, ...) 
from
  (select .... From TEmployee where ...) as TEmployeeAlias
  inner join 
  (select ... From TSalAdvance where ...) as TSalAdvance Alias
     on ...
  inner join  
  (select ... From TSalAdvance where ...) as TSalAdvance Alias
     on ...
  left outer join
  (select...) as tableN 
     on ...
```

Have you tried something like this ? If so what problems have you encountered ?